# Creating a Graph using Adjacency List

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I am following Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual v3.

I have seen a few questions stating that there are certain **typos** in the book, and I am not sure whether this is one or just because I cannot understand it.

Consider the following:

```
typedef struct edgenode {
    int y;                   /* adjacency info */
    int weight;              /* edge weight, if any */
    struct edgenode *next;   /* next edge in list */
} edgenode;

typedef struct {
    edgenode *edges[MAXV+1];  /* adjacency info */
    int degree[MAXV+1];       /* outdegree of each vertex */
    int nvertices;            /* number of vertices in the graph */
    int nedges;               /* number of edges in the graph */
    int directed;             /* is the graph directed? */
} graph;

void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed) {
    edgenode *p;        /* temporary pointer */

    p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));    /* allocate edgenode storage */

    p->weight = 0;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x];

    g->edges[x] = p;    /* insert at head of list */

    g->degree[x]++;

    if (!directed) {
        insert_edge(g, y, x, true);
    } else {
        g->nedges++;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, `void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed)` connects two nodes at array index `x` and `y` by adding them to `edges` array.

The following snippet confuses me:

```
p->y = y;
p->next = g->edges[x];

g->edges[x] = p;    /* insert at head of list */
```

How is this working? Suppose my input is `x = 3, y = 4`, and this is the first input.

I would expect something like `3 -> 4` for a directed graph.

1. `p->y = y;` makes perfect sense, the adjacent of `x` is `y`.
2. `p->next = g->edges[x];` But the `edges` array is initialized to null. Won't this make `3.next == NULL` instead of `3.next == 4`?
3. `g->edges[x] = p;` What? `edges[x] == x Node`, this confuses me.

The complete code can be found at [graph.c](https://github.com/SkienaBook/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Programs-V3/blob/main/graph.c) and [graph.h](https://github.com/SkienaBook/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Programs-V3/blob/main/graph.h).

I think `p.next = y;` somehow and `y.next = NULL` as of now i.e. the first insertion. Maybe it's my rusty C but need some help on this.

Comment: A proper implementation should create both `x` and `y` nodes IMO, this implementation looks strange to me. I tried to replicate it in Java, but all these points confused me.

Comment: `edges` is a linked list. That part is just prepending to that list. `.next` is actually the next edge in the linked list of edges. (Separately, I think `x` is implied somehow. Maybe this linked list is converted to an array later and `x` is implied from the array index?)

Comment: Yeah, you can see in `transpose` that `x` is implied from how deep into the linked list the edge is.

Comment: This is confusing, I get the analogy that a node has a next node, like a linked list, but edge has a next edge? This sounds confusing.

I will read more to make logical sense of this.

Comment: It's really just "thing" and "next thing". That part isn't related to nodes/edges in the context of graphs, it's strictly for managing data storage.

Comment: Oh, I got it. It's like you enter edges, which are stored in reverse order. Like if you enter 0 -> 2, 0 -> 3. The linked list would have 0 ->3 first and then 0 -> 2.

Comment: Just a correction to a comment above: `edges` is *not* a linked list: it is a (fixed size) array. There are linked lists at a deeper level: `edges[0]`, `edges[1]`, ... are linked lists (i.e. pointers to the first nodes of those lists), and new `edgenode` nodes are prepended to those lists, meaning that the head is always the newest added node and thus `edges[x]` needs to be updated at each insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, `insert_edge` connects two nodes at array index x and y by adding them to `edges` array.

I wouldn't call this "addding to `edges` array", since the `edges` array has a fixed length, and has an entry for each **node** (not for each **edge**).

The index of `edges` identifies the "from" vertex of an edge, and the `y` field of an `edgenode` identifies the corresponding "to" vertex of that same edge.

For each vertex `x`, this code maintains a linked list of edges (not `edges`, but `edges[x]`), which initially will be empty.

Let's do this for an example graph:

[image]

...which after initialisation is populated with its edges as follows:

```cpp
insert_edge(g, 0, 1, true); 
insert_edge(g, 0, 2, true); 
insert_edge(g, 1, 2, true); 
insert_edge(g, 2, 3, true); 
insert_edge(g, 3, 4, true);
```

Let's see how this populates the `graph` data structure. We start out with this state for `g` (where I will assume `MAXV` is 4 for this representation):

```
    ┌───────────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐    
g ─►│ edges     │  - │  - │  - │  - │  - │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
    │ degree    │  0 │  0 │  0 │  0 │  0 │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┴────┴────┴────┘
    │ nvertices │  5 │ 
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ nedges    │  0 │
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ directed  │true│
    └───────────┴────┘
```

The hyphens represent `nullpointer` values. I assume all this has been initialised properly.

Then `insert_edge(g, 0, 1, true)` will create a `p` node, which is allocated and initialised to this:

```
    ┌────────┬────┐
p ─►│ weight │  0 │
    ├────────┼────┤
    │ y      │  1 │
    ├────────┼────┤
    │ next   │  - │
    └────────┴────┘
```

Notably the `next` field is `nullptr`, because that is the value found at `g->edges[0]`.

Then the next statement `g->edges[x] = p` makes the link, and after two counters have been incremented, the function has finished its job:

```
                      ┌────────┬────┐
                  p ─►│ weight │  0 │
                      ├────────┼────┤
                      │ y      │  1 │
                      ├────────┼────┤
                   ┌─►│ next   │  - │
                   │  └────────┴────┘
                   │
                   │
                   │
                   │
    ┌───────────┬──│─┬────┬────┬────┬────┐    
g ─►│ edges     │  ┴ │  - │  - │  - │  - │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
    │ degree    │  1 │  0 │  0 │  0 │  0 │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┴────┴────┴────┘
    │ nvertices │  5 │ 
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ nedges    │  1 │
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ directed  │true│
    └───────────┴────┘
```

Now we get to the more interesting one: `insert_edge(g, 0, 2, true);`. Again `p` is pointed to a new `edgenode`, but this time `g->edges[0]` is not `nullptr` and so `p->next` will get to point to the previously added `edgenode`. After `insert_edge` finishes we get this:

```
                      ┌────────┬────┐  ┌────────┬────┐
                  p ─►│ weight │  0 │  │ weight │  0 │
                      ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                      │ y      │  2 │  │ y      │  1 │
                      ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                   ┌─►│ next   │  ────►│ next   │  - │
                   │  └────────┴────┘  └────────┴────┘
                   │
                   │
                   │
                   │
    ┌───────────┬──│─┬────┬────┬────┬────┐    
g ─►│ edges     │  ┴ │  - │  - │  - │  - │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
    │ degree    │  2 │  0 │  0 │  0 │  0 │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┴────┴────┴────┘
    │ nvertices │  5 │ 
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ nedges    │  2 │
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ directed  │true│
    └───────────┴────┘
```

And so it continues for the other edges: every time the new `edgenode` is prepended to a linked list of which the head pointer is stored in the `edges` array. We have 5 linked lists: one for each vertex.

Here is the end result for the above example:

```
                      ┌────────┬────┐  ┌────────┬────┐
                      │ weight │  0 │  │ weight │  0 │
                      ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                      │ y      │  2 │  │ y      │  1 │
                      ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                   ┌─►│ next   │  ────►│ next   │  - │
                   │  └────────┴────┘  └────────┴────┘
                   │       ┌────────┬────┐  ┌────────┬────┐
                   │       │ weight │  0 │  │ weight │  0 │
                   │       ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                   │       │ y      │  4 │  │ y      │  2 │
                   │       ├────────┼────┤  ├────────┼────┤
                   │    ┌─►│ next   │  ────►│ next   │  - │
                   │    │  └────────┴────┘  └────────┴────┘
                   │    │       ┌────────┬────┐
                   │    │       │ weight │  0 │
                   │    │       ├────────┼────┤
                   │    │       │ y      │  3 │
                   │    │       ├────────┼────┤
                   │    │    ┌─►│ next   │  - │
                   │    │    │  └────────┴────┘
                   │    │    │       ┌────────┬────┐
                   │    │    │       │ weight │  0 │
                   │    │    │       ├────────┼────┤
                   │    │    │       │ y      │  4 │
                   │    │    │       ├────────┼────┤
                   │    │    │    ┌─►│ next   │  - │
                   │    │    │    │  └────────┴────┘
    ┌───────────┬──│─┬──│─┬──│─┬──│─┬────┐    
g ─►│ edges     │  ┴ │  ┴ │  ┴ │  ┴ │  - │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
    │ degree    │  2 │  2 │  1 │  1 │  0 │
    ├───────────┼────┼────┴────┴────┴────┘
    │ nvertices │  5 │ 
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ nedges    │  6 │
    ├───────────┼────┤
    │ directed  │true│
    └───────────┴────┘
```

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: What a detailed answer!! Thanks a lot!